# Ｗhat is the difference between 終に、遂に、and 竟に？

Tags: meaning, kanji

Ｗhat is the difference between 終に、遂に、and 竟に? All of them are ついに and have the same meaning in english too "finally". Thank you ^^

Answer (score 1):

The reason ついに has three kanji is because the word was originally (i.e. a millennium ago) used to translate these three different Chinese adverbs:

- 終: in the end; finally
- 遂: consequently
- 竟: it turns out that; in fact

**But**, we no more intentionally distinguish these meanings, and most of them are already fallen into disuse in Japanese. Today we only recognize "finally" meaning while prefer 遂 kanji. You have no need to care about any difference between those kanji, only need to know that people could use any of them (plus all hiragana form) according to their tastes.